# Set timeout for alert in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I've created an alert message which I want to close after a set defined time only. Below is my code:

```js
showAlert() {
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ 
 subTitle: 'The information you have provided is incomplete or invalid. Please check your entries and check again.' 
 });
 alert.present();
}
```

showAlert() is the method that will be invoked after an event. Now, I want to set timeout for it but I couldn't get any solution for it.

Comment: _I want to set timeout for it_ you mean dismiss after an amount of time..? or create after some amount of time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use timeout to invoke alert,

you can use the global `setTimeout()` function like so:

```
showAlert() {
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ 
 subTitle: 'The information you have provided is incomplete or invalid. Please check your entries and check again.' 
 });
setTimeout(()=>alert.present(),3000);

}
```

In case you want to dismiss after timeout,

```
setTimeout(()=>alert.dismiss(),3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alert , prefer using toast for such issues , you can display it for as much time you want.

for using toast , you may proceed like mentioned below:

```
import {Toast} from 'ionic-native';
     Toast.show("The information you have provided is incomplete or invalid. Please check your entries and check again.", '3000', 'center').subscribe(
            toast => {
              console.log(toast);
            }
          );
```

"3000" : is the time for which you want to display , timing is in milliseconds , hence , 3000 = 3 sec. 
"center": is the position of the toast , it can either be top , center , or bottom.

Comment: Toast and alert are totally different. The fact that toasts have a timeout, doesn't mean they are suitable for this case

Comment: @MorKadosh as per the scenario that nikhil stated , seems like his purpose can be fulfilled by toast too.